can't get git tag within vercel ignore steps script
I am trying to check if the current commit has assigned a TAG, locally it works correct tag but within the ignore steps sh script on Vercel it's always undefined. Overall it seems that I can't get any information about tags in this env as I tried to log just list of all existing tags, which is also empty
echo "GIT_TAG: $(git name-rev --name-only --tags HEAD)"
echo "GIT_TAGS: $(git tag --list)"

the output is
GIT_TAG: undefined
GIT_TAGS: 
 - Build cancelled


you can use the command git tag --contains "your commit SHA". If you don't know what a code SHA is, it's basically a code of 40 characters that is created when you do a commit, it make so every commit is unique. If you don't know your code SHA, you can use git log to try and find it.

There is no problem with searching a tag for the current commit, but the fact, that when Vercel ignore build steps script runs it can't see any tags as the list of tags is empty for some reason.

Either

your build process doesn't fetch tags for some reason (add git fetch --tags somewhere in your workflow), or

the build does fetch tags, but you have some local tags that you have not pushed to the server (git push && git push --tags, or if your push triggers a remote build, git push --atomic REMOTE BRANCH_NAME TAG)


